# How to retrieve headers on AppHarbor hosted WCF-applications

Tags: wcf, http-headers, appharbor

Currently I have a WCF-based service deployed on AppHarbor. I'm having a issue with a GET operation defined like this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "feedcallback")]
        Stream HandleMessageGet();
```

And implemented like this:

```
public Stream HandleMessageGet()
{
    var value = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["header.name"];
    //Do stuff with header value
    return ms;
}
```

Whenever I run this WCF application on localhost for debugging etc. it works fine; I can retrieve the header value. But whenever I deploy the project to AppHarbor, the get request doesn't function properly anymore because it can't retrieve the header from the `WebOperationContext`.

What could be causing this issue and how could this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it seems to be an issue with the AppHarbor loadbalancer not forwarding headers with dots in them.

See: http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/37218-header-not-being-forwarded